# UITableViewCell imageView overlaps text in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a cell that has some text in it and was trying to add an image to the cell.

This is what Ive tried:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 30, 30)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[imageView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.jpeg"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid the image from overlapping the text in the cell? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

tableviewcells have their own imageView that will appear to the left of the content or atleast to the left of the cells text.

You are creating an extra imageView that just happens to have the same name.

Comment: is there a way to change the height and width of the cell.imageView? I've tried `cell.imageView.frame` but still no luck

Comment: For that your best bet is to modify the other data you have in the content view so it is next to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the location

```
cell.imageView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW11 which has a nice example of how to use the built-in UITableViewCell image view.

Every UITableViewCell already has an UIImageView property 'imageView', but it's only shown if you set the imageView properties image property (cell.imageView.image = /* image code */;)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is create a custom `UITableViewCell`. Or perhaps add another `UILabel` to the current cell and set your text in that instead of using the default `UILabel`.